# How to convert GET parameter from custom date format to database date format?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activerecord

In the `index` view of my `Invoice` model I have a form which `users` can use to filter the `invoices` by certain criteria:

```
<%= form_tag invoices_path, :method => 'get' do %>

    <%= text_field_tag :number, params[:number] %>

    <%= text_field_tag :after, params[:after] %>
    <%= text_field_tag :before, params[:before] %>

    <%= text_field_tag :min, params[:min] %>
    <%= text_field_tag :max, params[:max] %>

    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>

<% end %>
```

---

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @invoices = current_user.invoices.search(params)
  end

  ...

end
```

---

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  def self.search(params)
    data = all
    data = data.number_contains(params[:number]) if params[:number]

    data = data.date_is_after(params[:after]) if params[:after]
    data = data.date_is_before(params[:before]) if params[:before]

    data = data.total_is_more_than(params[:min]) if params[:min]
    data = data.total_is_less_than(params[:max]) if params[:max]

    data
  end

  def self.date_is_after(date)    
    where("date >= ?", date)
  end

  def self.date_is_before(date)    
    where("date <= ?", date)
  end

  ...

end
```

The problem is that to filter the invoices by date a user will have to enter the `after` and `before` parameters in the format that is used by the database, i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD` which is quite cumbersome for the user.

How can I make it that the user can search in his preferred `date_format` as it is specified in the `date_format` column of his `preferences` record, e.g. `%d.%m.%Y` or `%m/%d/%Y`?

It would be good if that custom date format was accepted by the search form.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The easiest way is to use a datepicker type component. Then you always get the right format. A simpler but more clunky alternative is to use comboboxes for day, month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to [`Date.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse):

```
▶ d = Date.parse '12/08/2014'
# => #<Date: 2014-08-12 ((2456882j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
▶ d = Date.parse '12.08.2014'
# => #<Date: 2014-08-12 ((2456882j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

And then simply:

```
▶ d.to_s
# => "2014-08-12"
```

Hope it helps.